# Scala: regex on lists/sequences

Tags: scala

Is there a systematic way to search for sub-sequence patterns in arbitrary given sequences? In a sense, it is like like regex, but over sequence of elements.

More specifically we want to complete this function

```
def findPattern(seq: Seq[String], Seq[String]): Seq[Int] = { 
  // find the indices of seq which matches the input pattern.
  // if the pattern is not found, return Seq.empty.
}
```

For example for the following inputs and the target pattern:

```
seq: Seq[String] = Seq("NNS", "VBG", "JJ", "NNS", "IN", "NNP", "NNP")
pattern: String = Seq("VBG", "JJ")
```

The desired output should be:

```
Seq(1, 2)
```

Another example with the same `seq`:

```
pattern: String = Seq("VBG", "?", "NNS")
```

And the desired output should be

```
Seq(1, 2, 3)
```

One more example:

```
pattern: String = Seq("VBG", "*", "IN")
```

which should result in:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Side note: one can make the output `Seq[Seq[Int]]` to accommodate existence of multiple patterns.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me why ? matches NNS (and why it doesn't match it in position 0) or why * also matches IN. Can you explain further?

Comment: If hte pattern was `Seq("VBG", "?", "NNS")` then it does make sense. '?` is then a wildcard for one element, `*` for one (or zero?) or more.

Comment: Oops that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: OK, so you want standard "glob" style matching with a different alphabet, in effect.  Will you ever need to have literal '* or '?' in your pattern? (i.e. do you need to have some form of escaping for those). A quick google turns up this: https://github.com/Arnauld/Steam/blob/master/src/main/scala/steam/util/Glob.scala - you'd need to make it work on Seq[A] not just String but that looks straightforward.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul good point. As you pointed out, we can define types for input and distinguish between "?" the label and the as wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

I think parser should more make sense for finding match pattern, There is an implementation for this, Hopeful, it's helpful for you:

```
  def findPattern(list: List[String], pattern: List[String]): List[List[Int]] = {
    def nextPattern(lt: Option[List[(String, Int)]], ps: List[String]): Option[List[(String, Int)]] = {
      ps match {
        //if only have "*" should return all
        case List("*") => lt
        //filter whether first str match head, if not return None
        case List(head) =>
          lt.filter(_.nonEmpty).filter(_.head._1 == head).map(r => {
            List(r.head)
          })
        //minimum match for wildcard for first str
        case "*" :: List(last) =>
          lt.filter(_.nonEmpty).flatMap(t => {
            t.find(_._1 == last).map(i => {
              t.takeWhile(_._1 != last) :+ i
            })
          })
        case "*" :: last :: l =>
          nextPattern(lt, List("*", last)).flatMap(j => {
            nextPattern(lt.map(_.drop(j.size)), l).map(i => {
              j ++ i
            })
          })
        //skip fist str
        case "?" :: l =>
          lt.filter(_.nonEmpty).flatMap(r => {
            nextPattern(Some(r.tail), l).map(j => {
              r.head :: j
            })
          })
        //match the list first str
        case head :: l =>
          lt.filter(_.nonEmpty).filter(_.head._1 == head).flatMap(r => {
            nextPattern(Some(r.tail), l).map(j => {
              r.head :: j
            })
          })
      }
    }
    //if any is empty, return None
    list.isEmpty || pattern.isEmpty match {
      case true => List.empty
      case false =>
        val relevantIndices = list.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 == pattern.head).map(_._2)
        val relevantSublists = relevantIndices.map(list.zipWithIndex.drop)
        relevantSublists.map{ sublist =>
          nextPattern(Some(sublist), pattern).map(_.map(_._2))
        }.filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
    }
  }
```

Test:

```
    val list = List("NNS", "VBG", "JJ", "NNS", "IN", "NNP", "NNP")

    println(findPattern(list, List("NNS", "VBG")))
    println(findPattern(list, List("NNS", "*", "VBG")))
    println(findPattern(list, List("NNS", "?", "VBG")))
    println(findPattern(list, List("NNS", "?", "JJ")))
    println(findPattern(list, List("VBG", "?", "NNS")))
    println(findPattern(list, List("JJ")))
    println(findPattern(list, List("VBG", "*", "IN")))
    println(findPattern(list, List("VBG", "*")))
    println(findPattern(list, List("Foo")))
    println(findPattern(list, List("VBG", "*", "Bar")))
    println(findPattern(list, List("NNS")))
```

which results in:

```
[info] List(List(0, 1))
[info] List(List(0, 1))
[info] List()
[info] List(List(0, 1, 2))
[info] List(List(1, 2, 3))
[info] List(List(2))
[info] List(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
[info] List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
[info] List()
[info] List()
[info] List(List(0), List(3))
```

Comment: Nice! Is this implementation part of a bigger project?

Comment: @Daniel, No, This implementation is by me for a try.

Comment: Any idea why it fails on this? 
```list: List(DT, NN, IN, DT, NNP, NNP, NN, VBD, IN, NN, ., DT, NN, NN, VBD, VBN, IN, CD, ., DT, VBG, VBD, NNP, CC, MD, VB, IN, NNP, .)
pattern: List(IN, NN)```

Comment: I made some minor changes to your code to cover some edge cases (like the example above) and multiple patterns. What you think?

Comment: Yes, you can do it.